# C: Avoid garbage values in linked-list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, printf, nodes

Suppose a word has multiple meanings in the dictionary. Actually, In my dictionary, one node has 5 meanings. So when I lookup the word, the program prints 2 meanings along with other 3 garbage values 100 characters long.

How can I avoid them from being printed?

Here's my code:

```
struct node{
    char word[20];
    char meaning[5][100];
    struct node *next;
};
void lookup(struct node *head, char *word)
{
  int found = 0, i;
  while(head != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(head->word, word) == 0)
    {
        found = 1;
        printf("\n\t%s", word);
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("\n\t%s", head->meaning[i]);
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }
    head = head->next;
  }
  if(found == 0) printf("\nWord not found in the dictionary!!");
}
```

Comment: Failure to initialise struct strings with NUL terminator, (guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allocate your node elements with calloc or do memset after malloc, so that all the memory (or members) of your node are filled with 0's by default.

```
struct node *node_element = (struct node *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
```

Then print the meanings by checking length,

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if(strlen(head->meaning[i]) > 0)
    printf("\n\t%s", head->meaning[i]);
}
```

Comment: not NULL - use zero --> '0'       NULL have a different meaning. see "man calloc"